# Convert csv to tsv taking a lot of CPU

Tags: python, python-3.x

A simple csv (from stdin) to tsv(stdout) with Python is taking 100% CPU for large files (GB..)

From `top`:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2430 nir      20   0  121288   8440   4656 R  99.0  0.1   0:59.56 python3
```

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#

import csv, sys

delimiter_char=','
quote_char='"'
if sys.argv[1:]:
        delimiter_char=sys.argv[1]
if sys.argv[2:]:
        quote_char=sys.argv[2]

csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect='excel-tab').writerows(
                csv.reader(sys.stdin,delimiter=delimiter_char, quotechar=quote_char))
```

The way I'm calling this script is from bash:

```
split -C 64M -d -a 4 --filter 'gzip > $FILE.gz' < (cat file.txt |  csv2tsv.py) split/file_
```

Any advice out to tune it?

Comment: Any chance you can use bash to do the conversion instead of Python? It'll probably be more efficient.

Comment: Perhaps `sed` could help; something like `sed -E 's/("([^"]*)")?,/\2\t/g' file`.

Comment: Post on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Please don't use CSV for large files  There are plenty of good options, like feather or parquet.

Comment: I already been down this road :( `sed` solution is not good when nested quotes are in a column. Also the input (csv) is not something I can control.

Comment: Maybe also try using `csv.writer.writerow` in conjunction with `sys.stdin.readline` in a loop? Could be that there are a lot of swap operations related to holding the whole stdin in memory with `csv.writer.writerows` and `sys.stdin.readlines`

Comment: I edited my question with how I use the script. @thebadgateway can you give example?

Comment: Well, the entire process is ultimately IO and CPU bound. It’s a good sign that it uses 100% CPU, in the sense that IO doesn’t seem to be the bottleneck. How long does it take for how many GB?

Comment: It is not really relevant. what I can say that it is faster than `sed`.  if I will not find a way to tune it I'm not sure I will want to use it in production as each run of it takes one CPU.

Comment: You would prefer it to use less CPU and run slower…? Converting GBs of data *will* take some processing power one way or the other, you’d want it to use as much CPU as possible to be over as quickly as possible.

Comment: Yeah. What @deceze said. CPU is high, but memory usage is low.

Comment: the -bad- `sed` takes 2x the time, with 10% CPU. I guess I can invest in fixing it. although python is faster it suffocate the machine - when there are 100 parallel processes I would need 100 CPUs - this is not making sense. Are we should this line can't be tuned?

Comment: Be aware of how many CPUs/cores the machine has, and restrict the number of parallel processes, putting jobs into a queue. Maybe run them with `nice`. Dedicate a machine just for this job if there are a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```py
mywriter = csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect="excel-tab")
line = sys.stdin.readline()
while line != "":
    mywriter.writerow(line)
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Comment: Oh drat. Maybe just symlink stdout to stdin 